# Calculate stderr, t-value, p-value, predict value for linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, predict, stderr, p-value

I'm fitting linear models with `MatrixModels:::lm.fit.sparse` and `MatrixModels::glm4` (also sparse).
However, these functions return `coeff`, `residuals` and `fitted.values` only.

What's the fastest and easiest way to get/calculate another values such as `stderr`, `t-value`, `p-value`, `predict` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the data from `MatrixModels:::lm.fit.sparse` example.
I built a custom function `summary_sparse` to perform a summary for this model.
All matrix operations are performed with `Matrix` package.
Results are compared with dense type model.

Note `lm.fit.sparse` have to be evaluated with `method = "chol"` to get proper results.

Functions:

```r
summary_sparse <- function(l, X) {
  
  XXinv <- Matrix::chol2inv(Matrix::chol(Matrix::crossprod(X)))
  se <- sqrt(Matrix::diag(XXinv*sum(l$residuals**2)/(nrow(X)-ncol(X))))
  ts <- l$coef/se
  pvals <- 2*c(1 - pnorm(abs(ts)))
  
  list(coef = l$coef, se = se, t = ts, p = pvals)
  
}

predict_sparse <- function(X, coef) {
  X %*% coef
}
```

Application:

```r
dd <- expand.grid(a = as.factor(1:3),
                  b = as.factor(1:4),
                  c = as.factor(1:2),
                  d= as.factor(1:8))
n <- nrow(dd <- dd[rep(seq_len(nrow(dd)), each = 10), ])

set.seed(17)

dM <- cbind(dd, x = round(rnorm(n), 1))
## randomly drop some
n <- nrow(dM <- dM[- sample(n, 50),])
dM <- within(dM, { A <- c(2,5,10)[a]
                   B <- c(-10,-1, 3:4)[b]
                   C <- c(-8,8)[c]
                   D <- c(10*(-5:-2), 20*c(0, 3:5))[d]
   Y <- A + B + A*B + C + D + A*D + C*x + rnorm(n)/10
   wts <- sample(1:10, n, replace=TRUE)
   rm(A,B,C,D)
})

X <- Matrix::sparse.model.matrix( ~ (a+b+c+d)^2 + c*x, data = dM)

Xd <- as(X,"matrix")

fmDense <- lm(dM[,"Y"]~Xd-1)

ss <- summary(fmDense)

r1 <- MatrixModels:::lm.fit.sparse(X, y = dM[,"Y"], method = "chol")

f <- summary_sparse(r1, X)

all.equal(do.call(cbind, f), ss$coefficients, check.attributes = F)
#TRUE

all.equal(predict_sparse(X, r1$coef)@x, predict(fmDense), check.attributes = F, check.names=F)
#TRUE
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! Is there a way to speed up calculations?

Comment: the biggest performance improvement might be done if the X'Xinv or X'X might be taken from regression model -  not evaluating it second time. Still there is no such possibility here. Even X'X has mn^2 flops - assessing crossproduct takes a lot of time. The current solution is quite decent one.